# Determine state of Show Desktop in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, desktop

Show Desktop performs two actions - either minimising open windows, or reopening the ones that weren't minimised.  Is there any way to find out (via a script preferably) what state it's in - whether the open windows are hidden or shown, and therefore what action it will take when you hit the button?

Comment: Why do you need to know? [xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: I'm using an application called Rainmeter to customise the desktop on my HTPC.  I have an HTPC view with 8 large icons for various media portals.  When entering this view, I minimise the open windows, or they sit over the desktop background. So when you enter the view it activates show desktop, all windows minimise - when you exit the view all you previously opened windows reopen. Except when you enter the view with all the windows minimsed, where they all pop open again.  It needs to be conditional on the current state of show desktop. Only show desktop if not already hiding the windows.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean the little square on the right-hand side of the taskbar next to the system tray.

That icon does not actually minimize any windows.  To the operating system the Desktop is a normal window that has no border or controls.  The only thing special about it is that it's always at the bottom of the Z-order.  Clicking that square temporarily raises it to the top of the Z-order (making it cover any open windows), but it does not minimize any existing open windows.  It will also return to the bottom of the Z-order instantly whenever another window regains focus.

In your program you could possibly get a handle to the Desktop window and check the Z-order position.  It should be the only window with a negative number (if memory serves).  There are Windows API calls that can get this information for you. As far as whether a scripting language could do it, I couldn't say.  I know that AutoIT and KiXtart both have functions that can spy on window control IDs, but I don't know if they could get that information from the Desktop window.